# I want to set alert on graph in the Grafana but I am not able to set

Tags: graph, alert, grafana, grafana-alerts

I want to set an alert on a graph in Grafana, but I am not able to set.

If the used value in graph exceeds above `27 TiB` then it should create an alert.

Also, I want slack notification of grafana graph **after every four or six hours**. But I am not able to see any option for that. Can you please help me regarding this

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could't you put on is above value from `14000000000000` to `27000000000000` (`27*10^12`)?!

Comment: Change `when avg()` to `when last()`

Comment: Thank You Benyamin.
I tried your solution but it is not working because I can put on value just as '14000000000000' or '27000000000000'.

Comment: If you could set alarm value to 27TB, what's the problem?

Comment: Alarm value is showing same result.

Comment: I want to alert for `used` value when it's `IS ABOVE` of  `27TiB`

Comment: Can I see your metrics? is the parameter (B)  "Used" one?

Comment: Yes parameter (B) is `used` one.

Comment: @Sepehrroosta  I have updated question with some details of `Axex` !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check the `Axes` tab --> `X-Axis` column: If you are calculating `Total` in the value part as you can see in the below

[image]

---

- Then, change the `avg()` to `sum()` in the `Condition`:

[image]

Comment: I tried this answer but it is still not working. I have updated question with `Axes` details. Can you suggest me what to do next !

Comment: @Abhijeet Now you are calculating Sum() of metric B in last 5 minutes, Change it to 1hour, Something like this: WHEN sum() OF query(B,1h,now) IS ABOVE ... – 

Note that your dashboard time range (Last 1 hour), makes your graph's value. –

Comment: What should be values for `If no data or all values are null` and `If execution error or timeout`

Comment: @Abhijeet These are for times when data is intrrupted or server is Disconnected.

Comment: Also, I want slack notification of grafana graph after every four or six hours. But I am not able to see any option for that. Can you please help me regarding this

Comment: @Abhijeet Have you added `slack` in notification channels?

Comment: Yes I have added `slack` notification channel. but grafana is not sending alerts only once it sent alert at beginning.

Comment: @Abhijeet In Grafana -> notification channels -> YOUR_SLACK_CHANNEL ; uncheck `send on all alerts` and `include image`, then try `Send Test`

Comment: @Abhijeet Please make a new question, then we can attach pictures.

Comment: It is sending notification to slack.

Comment: I want to send notification on slack channel after every 4 or 6 hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187377/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-sepehr-roosta).

Comment: You can find my new question on link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326655/i-want-to-set-alert-for-grafana-graph-after-every-four-hours-on-slack`