# I want to set Alert for grafana graph after every four hours on Slack

Tags: grafana, alerts, grafana-alerts

I want slack notification of grafana graph after every four or six hours. But I am not able to see any option for that. Can you please help me regarding this.
Advance Thank You.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mention `send reminder every` to value at what time period you want notifications.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

I recommend that just copy `URL` from your slack -> Incoming-webhook, then paste it on `Slack Settings`, for the first time, just fill `url` option and try `Send Test`.

Uncheck `Send on all alerts` and `Include image` and test it again.

Comment: I have tested and it is sending me alert also what I can to do next !